# How can I transfer a variable from one method to another without storing it in a class in Java?

Tags: java

I have a class with three methods in it for determining whether a credit card is valid or not, what the credit card type is, and for displaying the number with x's in place of all but the last four digits. This is for a class and my teacher does not want me to store the variable for the credit card in this class. So, in my other class I have to ask for the credit card number in a method and store it in that method. However, I want a second method that calls the methods for displaying the credit card type and displaying the formatted number, but I do not know how to transfer the variable from the first method to the next. Please help.

This is my readCreditCard method that asks for the credit card number and determines whether it is valid:

```
public void readCreditCard(CreditCard creditCard)
{
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter your Credit Card Number: ");
    String creditCardNum = keyboard.next();

    while (creditCard.isCardValid(creditCardNum) == false)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid credit card number" + creditCardNum);
        System.out.println("Please try again.");

        System.out.print("\nPlease enter your Credit Card Number: ");
        creditCardNum = keyboard.next();
    }


}
```

I want a method called printCreditCard that allows me to use the variable creditCardNum from the readCreditCard method so that I can use my other two methods in the CreditCard class, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

Here is the contents of the CreditCard class:

```
public boolean isCardValid(String creditCard)
{
    boolean valid;
    String singleDigitPrefix = creditCard.substring(0, 1);
    String doubleDigitPrefix = creditCard.substring(0, 2);

    if ((creditCard.length() == 13 || creditCard.length() == 16) && singleDigitPrefix.equals("4"))
    {
        valid = true;
    }
    else if (creditCard.length() == 16 && (doubleDigitPrefix.equals("51") || 
            doubleDigitPrefix.equals("52") || doubleDigitPrefix.equals("53") ||
            doubleDigitPrefix.equals("54") || doubleDigitPrefix.equals("55")))
    {
        valid = true;
    }
    else if (creditCard.length() == 15 && doubleDigitPrefix.equals("37"))
    {
        valid = true;
    }
    else
    {
        valid = false;
    }

    return valid;
}

public String getCardType(String creditCard)
{
    String cardType = null;

    String singleDigitPrefix = creditCard.substring(0, 1);
    String doubleDigitPrefix = creditCard.substring(0, 2);

    if ((creditCard.length() == 13 || creditCard.length() == 16) && singleDigitPrefix.equals("4"))
    {
        cardType = "Visa";
    }
    else if (creditCard.length() == 16 && (doubleDigitPrefix.equals("51") || 
            doubleDigitPrefix.equals("52") || doubleDigitPrefix.equals("53") ||
            doubleDigitPrefix.equals("54") || doubleDigitPrefix.equals("55")))
    {
        cardType = "MasterCard";
    }
    else if (creditCard.length() == 15 && doubleDigitPrefix.equals("37"))
    {
        cardType = "American Express";
    }
    else
    {

    }

    return cardType;
}

public String maskCardNumber(String creditCard)
{
    String formattedNum = null;

    if (getCardType(creditCard).equals("Visa"))
    {
        if (creditCard.length() == 13)
        {
            formattedNum = "XXXXXXXXX" + creditCard.substring(8, 13);
        }
        else
        {
            formattedNum = "XXXXXXXXXXXX" + creditCard.substring(11, 16);
        }
    }
    else if (getCardType(creditCard).equals("MasterCard"))
    {
        formattedNum = "XXXXXXXXXXXX" + creditCard.substring(11, 16);
    }
    else if (getCardType(creditCard).equals("American Express"))
    {
        formattedNum = "XXXXXXXXXXX" + creditCard.substring(10, 15);
    }
    else;

    return formattedNum;




}
```

}

Comment: instead of `void`, return the value of `creditCardNum`, perhaps ?

Comment: Or teach `CreditCard` how to print itself (add a `print()` method to it)? It's really unclear what you're actually trying to do here.

Comment: as i understand he wants to pass a value of creditCardNum from the read method to the print method...

Comment: Please post `CreditCard`.

Comment: I've added the CreditCard class. Does this help?

Comment: @amphibient If I return the value, would I have to add it as a parameter to my readCreditCard method?

Answer (score 1):

create a bean with Member variables called creditCardNum and etc ..the method return this bean to which method  need.

Comment: I don't know what a bean is. I'm very new to coding.

Comment: for example, u want to pass a person from method a to b..u can create a class named Person which has name,height,age...this called bean..

Comment: My teacher doesn't want me to do that though. I have a CreditCard class where I could introduce the creditCardNum variable, but my teacher does not want that

Comment: maybe,u can let creditCardNum to the member variable..and create getCreditCardNum() method.

Answer (score 0):

If i have understand your question correctly i see two option

**Option 1:** Return credit card number if it is single value you want.

```
public int readCreditCard(CreditCard creditCard)
{
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter your Credit Card Number: ");
    String creditCardNum = keyboard.next();

    while (creditCard.isCardValid(creditCardNum) == false)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid credit card number" + creditCardNum);
        System.out.println("Please try again.");

        System.out.print("\nPlease enter your Credit Card Number: ");
        creditCardNum = keyboard.next();
    }


}
```

**Option 2:** If you want to pass/return multiple values from method, passing the credit card object (bean/model) will solve your problem.

Here is the example.

```
 public class CreditCardBean{


        private String creditCardNumber;
        private Date expirationDate;


        public String getCreditCardNumber() {
              return creditCardNumber;
        }

        public void setCreditCardNumber(String creditCardNumber) {
            this.creditCardNumber = creditCardNumber;
        }

        public Date getExpirationDate() {
           return expirationDate;
        }

        public void setExpirationDate(Date expirationDate) {
          this.expirationDate = expirationDate;
       }

    }




public CreditCardBean readCreditCard(CreditCard creditCard)
{
    CreditCardBean bean = new CreditCardBean();
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter your Credit Card Number: ");
    String creditCardNum = keyboard.next();

    while (creditCard.isCardValid(creditCardNum) == false)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid credit card number" + creditCardNum);
        System.out.println("Please try again.");

        System.out.print("\nPlease enter your Credit Card Number: ");
        creditCardNum = keyboard.next();
        bean.setCreditCardNumber(creditCardNum);

    }
// Set other details which you want to pass.
// bean.setExpirationDate(<setDate here>); 
return bean;

}
```

Comment: If I do return the value, then I will have to include it as a parameter in my printCreditCard method, correct? If I do this, I'm not sure how to call the method in my driver class.

Comment: You need to declare new method with same name with return type.

Comment: I declare the method in the driver? Because that creates an error when I try to run it

Comment: Can you please share the exception you getting ?? Try to look if you are inheriting any interface or extending any other class and overriding the method from there.

Comment: I keep getting the Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0 in this line: String singleDigitPrefix = creditCardNum.substring(0,1);

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is happening because it is not reading the creditCardNum in that method.

Comment: Yep ...that's more likely.... Put a check for credit card number data validity and allow further execution only if data is valid.  Let me know if u need further help